# How to do two symmetric rectangular triangles in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I would like to do something like [this](https://image.ibb.co/kk4XoF/jajjf.jpg) with JavaScript. This is my code for creating the first half:

```
<script>
    var numberOfLines = 10;
    var str = '*';
    var space = '&nbsp';
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++){
        document.write(str + '<br>');
        str = str + "*";
    }
</script>
```

How can I finish it?

Comment: that's easy you can do it using spaces.

Comment: What do you mean by spaces ?

Comment: let's chat about it in the chat

Comment: Ok i don't know how to use that can you send me a message ?

Comment: okay let me work on it I will get back to you shortly

Comment: alright thanks alot

Comment: Copy the same text into two side-by-side divs, and use CSS to set the right-hand div to have right-aligned text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.join` to create your repeated characters. Use a monospaced font to preserve the space width.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

  var output = "";
  var numberOfLines = 10;

  for (lineNum = 0; lineNum < numberOfLines; lineNum++) {
    output += Array(lineNum + 2).join("*") + Array(((numberOfLines * 2) - (2 * (lineNum))) -1).join("&nbsp;") + Array(lineNum + 2).join("*") + "<br>";
  }

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = output;

});
```

```css
#result {font-family: monospace;}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not perfect but very close:

```js
var numberOfLines = 10;
var str = '*';
var arr = ["&nbsp;&nbsp;","&nbsp;&nbsp;","&nbsp;&nbsp;","&nbsp;&nbsp;","&nbsp;&nbsp;","&nbsp;&nbsp;","&nbsp;&nbsp;","&nbsp;&nbsp;","&nbsp;&nbsp;","&nbsp;&nbsp;","&nbsp;&nbsp;","&nbsp;&nbsp;","&nbsp;&nbsp;","&nbsp;&nbsp;","&nbsp;&nbsp;","&nbsp;&nbsp;","&nbsp;&nbsp;","&nbsp;&nbsp;"];
var spaces = arr.join("");
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
document.write(str + spaces + str + '<br>');
str = str + "*";
arr.splice(-1,1);
arr.splice(-1,1);
spaces = arr.join("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While simple in concept, there's actually a lot to consider when doing this, so lets analyze your code and build from there.

```
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
    document.write(str + '<br');
    str = str + "*";
}
```

this will loop through numberOfLines times. It will also output `str` `numberOfLines` times. Each loop, you're printing to the document; however, you would like to add a lot of spaces to `str` as well as a dynamic number of `*` characters before printing, and each time it will be a different number of spaces. Therefore, you either need to re-build `str` on each iteration of the loop, or build the entire string `str` prior to using `document.write()`

There are many different ways you can accomplish this, I'll go through two:

**With a function**

You can create a function to build each line. To do this, your function will need to know a few things:

- How many lines will there be?
- Which line are we currently on?
- What character should you use for the visible parts of the triangle?
- What character should you use for the invisible parts of the triangle?

So we can start by creating a function, we'll call it `generateTriangleLine`. 
To generate a line, we will want to look at how many of the visible character we want to show, and how many of the invisible. Because there are two sides to this, we will want to output twice as many characters as the current line number:

```
function generateTriangleLine(visible, invisible, numberOfLines, currentLine) {
// Let's initialize the line so that it has no characters:
var line = '';
// We want to output twice as many characters as there are lines
// So we will loop from 0 to (but not including) numberOfLines * 2
for (var i=0; i<numberOfLines*2; i++) {
    if (i<=currentLine || i>=(2*numberOfLines - currentLine - 1)) {
        // If we are at the beginning, or the end of the line, we want to output characters.
        // We want to add as many visible characters as the line number we are on!
        // At the end of the line, 2*numberOfLines = 20. If currentLine starts at 0,
        // we will want to draw one visible character, so we need to subtract one from this.
        line += visible;
    } else {
        // If we aren't at the beginning or end, just add the invisible character.
        line += invisible;
    }
}
// And we want to return the line:
return line;
}
```

In our code, we can then loop through `numberOfLines` times, generating each line using our function:

```
for (var i=0; i<numberOfLines; i++) {
    // We'll add a <br> to each line, so that it is drawn appropriately.
    document.write(generateTriangleLine('*', '&nbsp', numberOfLines, i) + '<br>');
}
```

If we run this, we'll get the appropriate output, but it won't necessarily be formatted correctly. This is because most fonts that you read on a daily basis have different widths for each character. The easiest way we can fix this is by wrapping our output in `<pre>` tags:

```
document.write('<pre>');
for (var i=0; i<numberOfLines; i++) {
    // We'll add a <br> to each line, so that it is drawn appropriately.
    document.write(generateTriangleLine('*', '&nbsp', numberOfLines, i) + '<br>');
}
document.write('</pre>');
```

**With a nested for loop to generate the entire output**

The other approach we can take is exactly the same as with the function above, but instead of calling a function to generate each line, we generate each line within for loops, and then output everything at the end altogether:

```
// The first loop will be for each line. 
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
    // The nested for loop will be for each character on each line
    // Remember, we have twice as many characters as we do lines
    for (var x = 0; x < numberOfLines * 2; x++) {
        // Just like we did in the function, we want to check
        // if we're at the beginning or the end of the line
        // Again, we subtract one from the end so that we still output at least one * on
        // the first line.
        if (x <= i || x >= (numberOfLines*2) - i - 1) {
            // If we are at the beginning or end, output the *
            str += "*";
        } else {
            // Otherwise, output the space
            str += space;
        }
    }
    str += '<br>';
}
```

Once again, we will get the correct output; however, we need to adjust for the letter widths so we can wrap our text in `<pre>` tags.

*Keep in mind, there are numerous ways to solve problems with programming. I've only provided a couple of examples. I would highly encourage you to practice by coming up with your own way of doing this using the skills you learn from the various responses!*